hvfloat-package in combination with hyperref-package
Here is my code:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
% \captionsetup{type=figure}
\hvFloat[nonFloat]
{figure}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{image.png}}
{Title}
{fig:test}
\end{document}

Running this, I get the following error message:
Package caption Warning: The option `hypcap=true' will be ignored for this
(caption)                particular \caption on input line 19.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

But the documentation is not helpful for this problem. Somewhere I found to add \captionsetup{type=figure} before the figure. Doing this, I get the message
 Package caption Warning: \setcaptiontype
  (caption)                outside box or environment on input line 11.
  See the caption package documentation for explanation.

Again, I checked the documentation unsuccessfully. In the hyperref-manual, I found the hint to \hyper@nopatch@caption. Unclear to me, how to do this (found no hint in the manual).

well basically it is a problem of hvfloat. It loads caption with the hypcap option but doesn't provide proper support and caption detects that. You can disable the hypcap support with \captionsetup{hypcap=false} to get rid of the warning.

@Ulrike, ok, now it is working without messages. It is unclear to me what consequences this hypcap=false has. Will study the manuals.
